# How do I configure a Linux VPN Client to get into a network through a Fortigate firewall?

Tags: linux, vpn, openswan

In order to connect to my job's VPN, I have been given by the network admin:

- a username
- a password
- a PSK

I run Ubuntu at home. I know Fortigate's VPN should be a vanilla IPSec, so OpenSwan should do the trick. Still, I can't get it to work.

I have tried a program called "Forticlient" for Linux that I found through Google but it doesn't have the appropriate fields for the 3 items listed above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out [Openfortivpn](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn). I had to resort to that, as our implementation of fortigate VPN doesn't have a functioning linux client. OpenfortiVPN works great for me:

`sudo openfortivpn -c /home/jarmund/vpnconfig`

my `/home/jarmund/vpnconfig`:

```
host = vpn.example.com
port = 10443
username = my.user@name.com
password = sUpErSecReTPasW0Rd
trusted-cert = 65568d85191ad188e19e3d9396fd0065899fa1645aef40d3c9ba8e3040b1166b
```

The trusted cert is the certificate offered by the VPN gateway, and will be displayed if you try to connect. Then you edit the config to add the certificate. Several certificates can be specifie on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got Fortigate here to test. But could you please try enter the `Server`, `User` and `Password`:

[image]

click to `Advanced Settings` button and check on `Use client certificate` and browse to your file:

[image]

I also gave up trying with Openswan 2 years ago: both of NETKEY and KLIPS.

Comment: The PSK I have is not a certificate file, just an 18 character alphanumeric string. This is why I can't put it into the Forticlient. Any ideas?

Comment: The Forticlient program for Linux is intended to be used with an SSL VPN. I didn't have any luck getting IPSec (OpenSWAN) working. I talked my sysadmin into allowing the SSL VPN and the program appears to work fine.